# Can you really call any Objective-C method on AnyObject?

Tags: swift

According to the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" iBook (near Loc 9) regarding `id` compatibility:

> You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type.

The example given in the book (shown below) does not compile, which seems to contradict the above statement. According to the book, the last line below should not execute because the `length` property does not exist on an `NSDate` object.

```
var myObject: AnyObject = UITableViewCell()
myObject = NSDate()
let myLength = myObject.length?
```

Instead, this fails to compile with a "Could not find an overload for 'length' that accepts the supplied arguments" error on the last line.

Is this a bug, a typo, or is the statement about calling any Objective-C method wrong?

Answer (score 1):

the compiler error is saying `length` is a function and you call it with incorrect arguments

you can do `myObject.length?()` which return `nil`

also `myObject.count?` will give you `nil` without compile error

```
 xcrun swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Cocoa
  2> var obj : AnyObject = NSDate()
obj: __NSDate = 2014-06-25 13:02:43 NZST
  3> obj.length?()
$R5: Int? = nil
  4> obj.count?
$R6: Int? = nil
  5> obj = NSArray()
  6> obj.length?()
$R8: Int? = nil
  7> obj.count?
$R9: Int? = 0
  8>
```

---

I think what compiler was doing is search all method and property that called `length`, it found some class provide `length()` but no class provide `length`, hence the error message. Just like when you call `[obj nonexistmethod]` in ObjC, compiler will give your error saying `nonexistmethod` does not exist even you call it on `id` type object

This is what happened if you try to call non-exist method in Swift

```
 14> obj.notexist?
<REPL>:14:1: error: 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'notexist'
obj.notexist?
^   ~~~~~~~~

 14> obj.notexist?()

<REPL>:14:1: error: 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'notexist()'
obj.notexist?()
^   ~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: But there are many classes that accept `length` rather than `length()`. For example, `var data = NSMutableData(); let otherLength = data.length` will compile and work.

Comment: @JefferyRPrice maybe it is compiler bug (or language defect). a possible reason that `length` for `NSData` not found because it is not ObjC property but normal method `-[length]` which makes sense to translate to `length()` instead of `length`

Comment: I can believe that, but would that qualify as a bug, typo, or imply that the statement about calling any Objective-C method is incorrect? Furthermore, the documentation says that the Obj-C declaration for length is `@property(readonly) NSUInteger length`.